# Ajax.ActionLink calls controller twice

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an issue with Ajax.ActionLink calling controller twice. I have read similar problems but i couldn't solve it. I'm not including jquery multiple times. I have checked it in source:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJGJv.png

GET Requests:

First:

```
curl "http://localhost:64240/Group/SetPrice?groupId=10&X-Requested-   With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1433799153696" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Referer: http://localhost:64240/Group" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36" --compressed
```

Second:

```
curl "http://localhost:64240/Group/SetPrice?groupId=10" -H "Accept:    text/html, */*; q=0.01" -H "Referer: http://localhost:64240/Group" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36" --compressed
```

Controller Method snippet:

```
public ActionResult SetPrice(string name, int? page, int groupId)
{
        ViewData["name"] = name;
        int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;
        ...
}
```

ActionLink:

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "SetPrice", new { groupId = item.GroupId },
 null, new { @class = "modal-link btn btn-info ion-gear-b", style = "font-  size: 12px;margin-right:10px;", title = "Set Price" })
```

Request Initiator

First Request:

```
send    @   jquery-2.1.4.js:8630 
jQuery.extend.ajax  @   jquery-2.1.4.js:8166
asyncRequest    @   jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:128
(anonymous function)    @   jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:138
jQuery.event.dispatch   @   jquery-2.1.4.js:4435
elemData.handle @   jquery-2.1.4.js:4121
```

Second:

```
send    @   jquery-2.1.4.js:8630
jQuery.extend.ajax  @   jquery-2.1.4.js:8166
jQuery.fn.load  @   jquery-2.1.4.js:8861
Modal   @   bootstrap.js:804
(anonymous function)    @   bootstrap.js:982
jQuery.extend.each  @   jquery-2.1.4.js:374
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each   @   jquery-2.1.4.js:139
$.fn.modal  @   bootstrap.js:977
(anonymous function)    @   bootstrap.js:1012
jQuery.event.dispatch   @   jquery-2.1.4.js:4435
elemData.handle @   jquery-2.1.4.js:4121
```

Comment: What initiated these calls? You can use the `Initiator` column in the dev tools under the Network tab.

Comment: First One :    send @ jquery-2.1.4.js:8630
jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.1.4.js:8166
asyncRequest @ jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:128
(anonymous function) @ jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:138
jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.js:4435
elemData.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.js:4121

Comment: It's impossible to read in a comment, please edit it into your question.